# Katalon (selenium) issues with setText on TextArea

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio

I am unable to setText to a TextArea.  Do I need to use the full xpath?
The error I am getting is:

=============== ROOT CAUSE =====================

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
At object: 'Object Repository/Page_The Mortgage Office/textarea_FundingNotes'

Here are the details of the Object:
'
Selected Locator: //textarea[@id='teNotes']

```
XPath:attributes://textarea[@id='teNotes']
XPath:idRelative://textarea[@id='teNotes']
XPath:position://div[7]/div/textarea
XPath:customAttributes://div[7]/div/textarea
```

**Inspecting it in Chrome:**

```
<textarea name="teNotes" id="teNotes" class="form-control-sm form-control" rows="3" style="resize: none;" maxlength="255" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Full XPath:

```
/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[7]/div/textarea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the object was not editable.  This means that I couldn't just use sendKeys directly, I had to first Click the object, THEN sendKeys.

Thank you!

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject('TM_Loans/input__OriginalAmount'))

WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('TM_Loans/input__OriginalAmount'), '100000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Verify is the text area is present and then do settext/Sendkeys.

use direct xpath/ change the xpath for the textarea method to //textarea[@id='teNotes']

for Verification use WebUI.VerifyElementPresent keyword.

this should solve the issue.